# Unable to cast object of type 'WindowsFormsApplication5.Form3' to type 'WindowsFormsApplication5.Form2'

Tags: c#, winforms

I started to work on multiple form application. I will have around 50 forms in one application. The problem is next:
I want to every form after `Form2` (I mean `Form3`, `Form4`, `Form5` etc.) to have button that will show `Form2` again and close current one. Here is code for making `Form2`:

```
Form2 form2 = new Form2();
form2.Tag = this;
form2.Show(this);
Hide();
```

And there is code to get back to `Form2` from any form which is after `Form2`:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var form2 = (Form2)Tag;
    form2.Show();
    this.Close();
}
```

When i run the program it all works, except when I click on button in any Form after `Form2` to get back to `Form2` i get following error:

> InvalidCastException was unhandled
>   An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in WindowsFormsApplication5.exe
>
> Additional information: Unable to cast object of type 'WindowsFormsApplication5.Form3' to type 'WindowsFormsApplication5.Form2'.

Comment: you should do something like this var form2 = (Form2)Form2.Tag;

instead of this         var form2 = (Form2)Tag;

Comment: @KhurramAli What would be the point of that?

Comment: @DavidG: He is typecasting as (Form2) by tag property but does not giving any reference of tag property..
by doing this Form2.Tag its reference the Tag of Form2 and then i am type casting

Comment: @KhurramAli The point being that the reference isn't a `Form2`, it's a `Form3` as the error suggests. And in another form it may be something else.

Comment: How are the other forms opened?  From Form2? Or via some kind of ribbon/toolstrip?

Comment: private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Form4 form4 =new Form4();
            form4.Tag = this;
            form4.Show(this);
            this.Hide();

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing this:

> form2.Tag = this;

With this:

> form2.Tag = form2;

Comment: The problem is in
 var form2 = (Form2)Tag;

Comment: Yes, because you assign 'this' to the tag, and later you cast the tag to Form2 and get an error. I'm not sure where you are when you assign 'this', so I don't know what 'this' is, but it's certainly not the form2 object because that's called form2. Just try it, but +1 to the comment about dubious architecture.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your `Tag` property can hold a reference to any form, not just `Form2`, so when you cast it, it will throw an error.

Instead, cast it to the `Form` base class:

```
var form = (Form)Tag;
form.Show();
this.Close();
```

However, this does sound like a really nasty way of keeping a reference to the 'main' form. I'd look at your architecture before doing this.

Comment: I dont want to cast it to base class.
Because when user pass to Form30 he will want on one click to get back to Form2, because from Form2 he can go to any form. With this code that you gave me it will return him from Form30 to Form29 etc..